# Mathcad doesn't calculate an expresion

Tags: math-software

could anyone help how to force Mathcad to calculate an expression.
After some steps I got such result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLg8G.png

but how can I get the result of such expression?

Thank you!

Comment: If you found an expression, what do you mean with result? An evaluation? The image you attached is not good enough to read it.